# PromQL "where" clause

Tags: kubernetes, where-clause, prometheus, promql

How does one add a where clause in PromQL?

I'm trying to construct a query that displays when an application running in Kubernetes has been up for more than one minute but I want to filter by namespace.

This is what my query looks like at the moment

```
100 * (count(up == 1) BY (job, namespace, service) ) > 1
```

This works fine but it gives me additional information that I don't need.

```
{job="prometheus-grafana", namespace="monitor", service="prometheus-grafana"}
{job="jenkins", namespace="jenkins", service="jenkins"}
{job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="monitor", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics"}
{job="node-exporter", namespace="monitor", service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
{job="kubelet", namespace="kube-system", service="prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet"}
{job="apiserver", namespace="default", service="kubernetes"}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get results for only the `jenkins` and `default` namespace.

```
{job="apiserver", namespace="default", service="kubernetes"}
{job="jenkins", namespace="jenkins", service="jenkins"}
```

I've tried doing

```
100 * (count(up == 1) BY (job, namespace, service) ) > 1 and ON {namespace="jenkins"}
```

But I get an `invalid parameter "query": 1:65: parse error: unexpected "{" in grouping opts, expected "("` error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to filter the metric "up" by the labels you want (namespaces) in your case it should look something like this:

```
100 * count(up{namespace=~"default|jenkins"} == 1) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Petar. This has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try this too. In Kubernetes all resources uses pod. So if you take pod status metrics and minus current time with 60, which gives post 1 min pods running status.

`time()-60 > (kube_pod_start_time)`

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus provides the following ways for filtering the data in queries:

- [Time series selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). They allow filtering time series by [metrics and labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels). For example, `up{namespace=~"default|jenkins"}` is a series selector, which returns only time series with the name `up`, which contain label `namespace` matching the given given [regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax): `default|jenkins`. This is roughly equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'up' and namespace ~ '^(default|jenkins)$'
```

- [Comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators), which allow filtering time series by values. For example, `up == 0` returns time series with `up` name, which have `0` value. This is roughly equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'up' and value == 0
```

- [Time series matching via binary operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching). This allows performing join-like queries. For example, `up * on(instance) group_left(name) node_os_info` joins `up` metric with `node_os_info` metric via `instance` label and selects additional `name` label from `node_os_info` metric. This is roughly equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT up.*, node_os_info.name
FROM up LEFT JOIN node_os_info ON (instance)
```